# Indeterminate expression in FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find roots around the maximum point ($ instante1 $) or, at least, one of the roots, so I can use the interval between the roots as a search range in the following calculations. Nevertheless, the FindRoot function is complaining about `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.`, and I am unable to find what is causing this problem. Does anyone can spot the error? I thought that the roots would be easily found, as they can be seen in the plot.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f0u = 500*10^6; f0d = 35*10^8;
f1u = 35*10^8; f1d = 500*10^6;
T = 1*10^-7;
ku = (f1u - f0u)/T;
kd = (f1d - f0d)/T;
phi0 = 0;
chplusu[t_] := E^(I*2*\[Pi]*((ku*t^2)/2 + f0u*t + phi0))
chplusd[t_] := E^(I*2*\[Pi]*((kd*t^2)/2 + f0d*t + phi0))
fsig1 = 16*10^8; fsig2 = 225*10^7; fsig3 = 3*10^9;
x[t_] := Cos[2*Pi*fsig1*t] + Cos[2*Pi*fsig2*t] + Cos[2*Pi*fsig3*t]
s1u[t_] := x[t]*chplusu[t]
s1d[t_] := x[t]*chplusd[t]
snu[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*(f0u*t + phi0))
snd[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*(f0d*t + phi0))
y2u[t_] := s1u[t]*snu[t]
y2d[t_] := s1d[t]*snd[t]
chmoinsu[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*((ku*t^2)/2 + f0u*t + phi0))
chmoinsd[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*((kd*t^2)/2 + f0d*t + phi0))
y1u[t_] := Convolve[y2u[to]*UnitStep[to], chmoinsu[to]*UnitStep[to], to, t, Assumptions -> t >= 0]
y1d[t_] := Convolve[y2d[to]*UnitStep[to], chmoinsd[to]*UnitStep[to], to, t, Assumptions -> t >= 0]
yu[t_] := y1u[t]*chplusu[t]
yd[t_] := y1d[t]*chplusd[t]
instante1 = (fsig1 - f0u)/ku
Plot[Evaluate[Re[yu[t] + yd[T - t]]], {t, instante1 - 0.5*10^-9,  instante1 + 0.5*10^-9}, PlotRange -> Full, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> {{instante1}, {Re[yu[instante1] + yd[T - instante1]]}}, ImageSize -> Full]
temp = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Re[yu[t] + yd[T - t]]], t > 0]
FindRoot[temp, {t, instante1}]
```

Comment: You have a singularity at the `instante1` point. Try `FindRoot[temp,{t,(1+1/100)*instante1}` and it will give `{t -> 3.69901*10^-8}`. I did not dive into why your function has singularity at that particular point. That goes beyond the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into your expression you will see something like this

$ (some therms)*\frac{400 \sin (3200000000 \pi  t)}{(100000000 t+7) (300000000 t-11)}*(..rest of expression...)$

clearly at point

$t=11/300000000=3.6666666666666664e^{-8}$

you have division by zero. This was your initial point.

If you start your search with some other initial point

```
FindRoot[temp,{t,(1+1/100)*instante1}
```

you will reach a solution

```
{t -> 3.69901*10^-8}
```

Comment: Thank you! but this show that I have to find another way to compute the roots, as if I choose (1+1/1000)*instante1, for instance, a point nearer the value where the maximum occurs, it will jump the root nearer this point to find another one.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand your question. That is how numerical root finding works. You gave initial value it looks for a first root around that initial value. Did you read help of [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)? You also have a tutorial on [numerical root finding](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalRootFinding.html) using Mathematica.

Comment: Well, I read. Your initial value (3.70333*10^-8) is very close to the root value (3.69901*10^-8). I just tried to bring the initial value closer to the value where the maximum occurs (I brought it to 3.67033*10^-8, while the maximum occurs at 3.66667*10^-8). Looking at the plot, it can be seen that the nearest root is still 3.69901*10^-8, even though, now, it finds 3.74423*10^-8 as the nearest root.

Comment: If I try with your starting point (3.67033*10^-8),   `FindRoot[temp == 0, {t, 3.67*10^-8}, DampingFactor -> 0.15, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10]`, I get the solution `{t -> 3.69991*10^-8}`, which is again expected. As I said, check the tutorial and help for `FindRoot`. If there are still some doubts please either search for a similar problem on this website or pose another question and be specific about the problem.